# Random error - docker hosted Java Springboot Application for GoDddy SMTP - Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: smtpout.secureserver.net

Tags: java, smtp, windows-server-2019, windows-firewall

**Context: -**

I am using a docker-hosted Java code which uses GoDaddy email service to sent notifications

MailerDeamonService.java

```
    public boolean sendEmail(String to, String subject, String text) {
    try {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtps");
        props.put("mail.smtps.host", SMTP_HOST_NAME);
        props.put("mail.smtps.auth", "true");

        Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
        Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport();
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
        MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("related");
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(emailId));
        message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to)); 
        message.setSubject(subject);
        messageBodyPart.setContent(text, "text/html");
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        message.setContent(multipart);

        transport.connect(SMTP_HOST_NAME, SMTP_HOST_PORT, emailId, new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(password)));
        transport.sendMessage(message, message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
        transport.close();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        errorReportService.generateErrorReport(e, "service", "MailerDaemonService", "sendEmail");
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Situation**

I am running this on 4 different AWS linux servers for different environments and it has been working perfectly for months.

**Problem**

I recently deployed my application on a client-server

It is a Windows Server 2019.

For about 2 weeks, this didn't give me any problems.

2 days ago, The emails suddenly stopped working with the error

```
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: smtpout.secureserver.net
```

While trying to debug this, I tested the command

```
telnet smtpout.secureserver.net 465
```

When I do this, the screen goes blank.
But for some reason, the emails started going through.

What should I be doing next to debug this?